# RxJava: count emitted elements during emitting

Tags: rx-java

I want to know which item has been just emitted by a blocking long running observable which will emit thousands of items. The code below works, but it creates a huge buffer of coming from `range()`.

```
sourceOservable
.zipWith(Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE), (any, counter) -> counter)
.whatever(...)
```

Is there any way to avoid this behavior without introducing any external counter field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer is due to the Observable.range. It may produce way faster than the sourceObservable. It has to buffer all values in order to zip with the right one from sourceObservable.

Please have a look at my implementation:

```
@Test
void stackoverflow44004014() {
    Observable.just("i", "b", "c")
            .scan(0, (counter, sourceValue) -> {
                return ++counter;
            })
            .skip(1)
            .test()
            .assertResult(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: That was I was looking for. Thank you. I just needed to change the counter to be a pair holding a source value and int to be able to propagate the source value further down the stream together with the counter.